# How to uninstall all versions of pip on Mac Catalina OS

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, pip

I got a new MacBook and transferred some apps over from my old MacBook with the Migration Assistant. I had pip installed on my old Mac. I didn't think it would be installed on the new Mac so I attempted to install in using the following command:
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
followed by:
`python3 get-pip.py`

When I tried to check if it was installed with `pip3 --version` I received the following warning:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
```

I've tried uninstalling pip with `python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools`, but this only produces `[Errno 13] Permission denied` errors. I've tried using chmod 755 to change the permissions of the python files that show up when I run `ls -la` but it doesn't seem to change anything and I still get the `[Errno 13]` errors.

Is there a way to change all permission on my Mac? Or else is there a way to uninstall all versions of pip?

I also have Conda installed, but I dont think that is an issue here.

Thanks.